# Genexus 15 U10 en iOS sale error "No module GXAudio found"

Tags: ios, genexus15

Tengo un inconveniente al tratar de compilar mi proyecto iOS con Genexus 15 U10 con Xcode 9.3 (9E145). Me sale que no se pueden encontrar los módulos de las librarías de Genexus y no me permite hacer Build al proyecto.

**NOTA:** Cabe recalcar que tengo que abrir el proyecto .xcworkspace con el Xcode para poder ver el error exacto.

**NOTA 2:** Además me aseguré que las librerías (.framework) de Genexus se encuentren dentro de las carpeta "/Users/USER/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/15.0.123190_U10"

[image: Screenshot 1]

```
<unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cxgevdwewdnzntfqxpkebjadwduz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/MyApp-Bridging-Header-swift_U6BX7CP55HQ7-clang_UAQJOSERRE9S.pch' for bridging header '/Users/USER/Documents/Projects/MyApp/dotNet Environment/MyApp/MyApp-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Comment: Peter Arcentales, estoy teniendo el mismo problema con Genexus 16 u4 para compilar en XCode. **¿Recuerdas qué pasos tomaste para corregir este error?**

Comment: Que tal @ChristianAbreu. Primero te recomiendo que hagas un Rebuild All. Luego abrir el proyecto Xcode generado. Si el problema sigue, entonces te va a tocar arreglar las rutas de todas las dependencias (librerías) que usa Genexus. Abre el Xcode y mira "Embed Frameworks". Cada librería de Genexus (GX...) debe estar haciendo referencia a una ruta que seguramente no existe o no encuentra. Puedes modificar una a una con la ruta real que debería ser algo como "User/Genexus/Genexus/16.XXXX_U4/NombreDeLibreria.framework". (no recuerdo la ruta exacta, pero debe ser donde se instalo el Genexus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probaría hacer una limpieza del proyecto para ver si se soluciona:

1. En Xcode, Product > Clean
2. Build

Si eso no lo arregla, entonces probaría borrando el directorio de Derived Data:

1. En Xcode, Preferences..., Locations, ir al directorio donde se encuentra la Derived Data
2. Borrar el contenido de dicho directorio
3. En Xcode, Product > Clean
4. Build

Si el problema persiste, entonces además de los puntos 1. a 3. del comentario anterior, borraría el directorio `~/GeneXus/GeneXus/Library/15.0.123190_U10`, el directorio del proyecto (`~/Documents/Projects/<KB_name>/<Main_object_name>`), el directorio `mobile` debajo del directorio de la KB en Windows, y haría un Rebuild del Main en GeneXus.

Comment: Hola que tal. Estuve revisando un poco más detalle las rutas utilizadas de las librerías de Genexus y pudo ver que el inconveniente era por un workaround que hice hace tiempo para que me compile iOS. De todas maneras gracias por al ayuda.